# Google Drive Android API still showing metadata of deleted files

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am developing an Android application that backs up and restores images on Google Drive. I have implemented the Backup and Restore part successfully.

But I am facing one problem right now that is, when I delete images from the Google Drive Web interface and then get MetaData of images from Google Drive using the Android app it still returns the metadata of the deleted files. I don't know why it's doing this.
I also removed the files from trash (Deleted Permanently). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack please show the code that is not working

Comment: Solved it actually Google Drive keeps meta data for a long time even if files related to that is deleted don't know where and why. When i tried same code again after couple of hours it worked.

Comment: @ZiaurRehman same problem here....have you find any solution?